# If you delete a label and ALL contacts in it, will that also delete those contacts from other labels?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, google-contacts

There are 1253 contacts separated by last name Alpha in 26 labels.  I just imported the list to create ONE label for ALL those contacts.  Now the number of contacts has doubled.  I want to get rid of the two new labels, but am fearful if I deleted the label and all the contacts within it - the contacts in the individual alpha folders will also be deleted.  That is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the labels. Deleting labels won't delete contacts or messages tagged to these labels.

To get rid of duplicate contacts merge them.

From [Google Contacts Help](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7078226?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> If you have duplicate listings for the same person in Google Contacts, you can merge them.
>
> You can't merge contacts that are saved in different Google Accounts.

> **Merge duplicates**
>
> 1. Go to Google Contacts.
> 2. On the left, click **Duplicates**.
> 3. In the top right, click **Merge all**. Or, review each duplicate and click **Merge**.